# Restassured - Facing issue with SSL - Untrusted Resources

Tags: ssl-certificate, rest-assured

I have tried following things-
 Ist thing - Using -RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
 RestAssured.given().proxy(ProxySpecification.host("proxy.corp.ups.com").withPort(8080).withAuth(User, Password)).when().get(url);
•Getting Status code as 502...

2nd Thing- I downloaded the PEM file from Browser and then convert it into the .jks file using
 $ keytool -importcert -alias "equifax-ca" -file EquifaxSecureGlobaleBusinessCA-1.crt -keystore truststore_javanet.jks -storepass test1234

then using
 InputStream keyStoreStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ABC.jks");
 KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
 keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, "Password".toCharArray());
   response = RestAssured.given().proxy(ProxySpecification.host("proxy.corp.ups.com").withPort(8080).withAuth(UName, Pwd)).trustStore(keyStore).when().get(url);

getting error - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)

Please help me with the above issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same problem I faced sometime ago, but in my case I solved the issue with this command:

```
sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure
```

More on this here: https://brunozambiazi.wordpress.com/2016/01/19/java-security-invalidalgorithmparameterexception-the-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty/